# Is it possible to set angular Service Worker to be disabled on different route in same domain?

Tags: angular, service-worker

I have different url for angular consumer ui and graphql api.
I have them wrangled up in on gateway url.
example)

- http://angulerapp.com => consumer ui page.
- http://angularapp.com/api
  => graphql api.

Right after I access angularapp.com and try to goto angularapp.com/api/graphiql to access graphql api doc, my service worker tries to load consumer ui.
is there any possible way to disable to load for consumer ui when i try to access graphiql interface?

Answer (score 0):

First, service worker and your client-code (aka Angular) run in separate contexts, so they are not related.

Now to the core of your question.

No, you cannot disable the service worker by route. It runs whenever a page within its scope it executed.

What you have to do is construct your service worker logic to handle different routes as you need. You can parse the event.request.url to determine if the URL matches a path rule to trigger your workflow. You can also parse by method and other request headers.